# Rotate External Display with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and have an NVIDIA GeForce 940M graphics card (proprietary NVIDIA drivers are installed for this). I have an external monitor that I want to rotate Counter-Clockwise (I doubt it matters, but specifically this is the Oculus Rift whose screen I am trying to rotate). It works correctly with most games/programs that I run on it, but everything i sideways because I can't rotate the display.

When I tried to do it from the command line by running `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left`, I get the output: `xrandr: output HDMI-1 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"`. The same is evident when I go to the display settings app, when I click the "rotation" drop-down, the only option is "Normal". I, of course, did a bit of research before posting this, but from what I could tell by trying `xrandr` again after making the changes, it didn't work. My xorg.conf file looks like this (generated from NVIDIA X server settings app):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "RandRRotation" "on"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "RandRRotation" "True"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

The additions I made were `Option "RandRRotation" "True"` and `Option "RandRRotation" "on"`. I feel like I'm missing something, but I'm not very good with X11, especially with display configuration files like `xorg.conf`. Is there something more I could do, something I am missing from all of this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: struggle is real.. i can't find a solution to this

Comment: Make Rotation Great Again!

Comment: Apparently canonical has patched X to not allow rotation for Nvidia drivers https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/post/5108881/#5108881

Comment: @MaxN actually these bugs, from 2011 until 2014, have been fixed with " reenable rotation"

Comment: @RobertRiedl No. This issue was fixed by Timo Aaltonen on 2017-06-26 https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNc19.png

Comment: @MaxN what do you mean "**No**"? Thats litarally the answer to [Bug1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1489696/comments/9), [Bug2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1308515/comments/12) and [Bug3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1386620/comments/16) of the Bugs posted by NVIDIA in the [devtalk thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/post/5108881/#5108881) you posted ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl this question was posted 2016 and the bug affected Ubuntu until mid 2017. "from 2011 until 2014" is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

Timo Aaltonen has fixed this issue on on 2017-06-26. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNc19.png